# My CSS grid element won't extend across multiple columns

Tags: html, css

I can't get my div element to span multiple columns in the CSS grid. What have I done wrong?

```css
.main {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-areas: "a b"
                               "c c";
          grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
          grid-template-columns: 200px 150px;
          }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
  <div id=a>
    <p>
      This is the content of box A.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id=b>
    <p>
      This is the content of box B.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id=c>
    <p>
      This is the content of box C.
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is an image of the output of the above code.:

[image: Here is an image of the output of the above code.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the grid area an element belongs to explicitly.

```
#a { grid-area: a; }
#b { grid-area: b; }
#c { grid-area: c; }
```